# how to select 5 correctly predicted images from each class

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, mnist

how can I select 5 correctly classified images for each class out of 10 classes so in total I want to have 50 images and send each one to another function? in the following code I was able to select the correct predicted image but how can I limit the number of images to 5 images per class?

```
for image, label in test_loader :
    image = image.view(-1, 784).requires_grad_()
    model.eval()
    out = model(image)

    _, predict = torch.max(out.data, 1)
    if predict.item() == label.item(): # here I want to count the correct classified image from each class and check that I want to send 5 images only 
    result= function(image, label)
```

Comment: Append the predicted image to a label_dict = defaultdict(list) where the key is the label and the value is a list of images... 
You can just append the if len(label_dict[label]) < 5 and then iterate for each image in each label.